# How can I set a pandas dataframe with the first value is what stays?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I got the following table with repeated values per person:

| Customer | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | Jun | Jul |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 345 | 345 | 345 | 345 | 345 |  |
| Susan |  |  | 645 | 645 | 645 | 645 |
| Paul |  | 153 | 153 | 153 | 153 |  |

You can see that the first value is actual value. So that table should be like that:

| Costumer | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | Jun | Jul |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 345 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Susan |  |  | 645 |  |  |  |
| Paul |  | 153 |  |  |  |  |

What's the better approach to solve this table?

Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'Customer': ['Adam', 'Susan', 'Paul'],
             'Jan': [345.0, np.NaN, np.NaN],
             'Feb': [345.0, np.NaN, 153.0],
             'Mar': [345.0, 645.0, 153.0],
             'Apr': [345.0, 645.0, 153.0],
             'Jun': [345.0, 645.0, 153.0],
             'Jul': [np.NaN, 645.0, np.NaN]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `mask` the duplicate values:

```
out = (df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(), axis=1)).fillna(''))
```

Output:

```
  Customer    Jan    Feb    Mar Apr Jun Jul
0     Adam  345.0                          
1    Susan                645.0            
2     Paul         153.0
```